# Template for custom admin panel tab

Tags: module, adminhtml, admin-panel, admin-controller

I've created a module which creates a custom tab in the admin panel but I've not been able to display the required data.`

This is my config.xml file

Path: app/code/community/Rohan/CreateAdminController/etc

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rohan_CreateAdminController>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rohan_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <rohan_createadmincontroller>
            <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
            <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
        </rohan_createadmincontroller>
    </helpers>
</global>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <Rohan_CreateAdminController>
                <file>rohan_createadmincontroller.xml</file>
            </Rohan_CreateAdminController>                
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>        

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <foo_bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">Rohan_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</foo_bar>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This is my adminhtml.xml file

path: app/code/community/Rohan/CreateAdminController/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
    <mycustomtab module="rohan_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
    <title>My Custom Tab</title>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
        <index module="rohan_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
          <title>Index Action</title>
          <sort_order>1</sort_order>
          <action>adminhtml/custom</action>
        </index>

        <list module="rohan_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
          <title>List Action</title>
          <sort_order>2</sort_order>
          <action>adminhtml/custom/list</action>
        </list>

        <third module="rohan_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
          <title>Third Action</title>
          <sort_order>3</sort_order>
          <action>adminhtml/custom/third</action>
        </third>

        </children>
    </mycustomtab>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <custom translate="title" module="rohan_createadmincontroller">
                    <title>My Controller</title>
                    <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title">
                            <title>Index Action</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </index>
                        <list translate="title">
                            <title>List Action</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </list>
                    </children>
                </custom>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

`
This is my CustomController.php file

Path: app/code/community/Rohan/CreateAdminController/controllers/Adminhtml

```
<?php

class Rohan_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));
    // my stuf

    echo "index";

    $this->renderLayout();

 }

public function listAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('List Action'));

    // my stuff
    echo "list"; 
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function thirdAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('Third Action'));

    // my stuff
    echo "third"; 
       $this->renderLayout();
   }
}
```

This is the result [image]

I want to display something in the main area. I know i need to create layout and template files for this but I can't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a layout file, add a rohan_createadmincontroller.xml file at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/rohan_createadmincontroller.xml.

This file should look something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_custom_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_index" template="custom/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custom_index>
    <adminhtml_custom_list>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_list" template="custom/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custom_list>
    <adminhtml_custom_third>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_third" template="custom/third.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custom_third>
</layout>
```

Then you will need to create templates at app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/template/custom/index.phtml, app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/template/custom/list.phtml, and app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/template/custom/third.phtml. In those template files put whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Although added the templates at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/custom instead of app/design/frontend